# Bootstrap nav hamburger button not appearing

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to do the basic  bootstrap navbar hamburger button on a collapsed screen. I am first just trying to get the button to be displayed but currently it won't display to the screen.

```
<nav class="navbar bg-light navbar-expand-sm">
  <h1 class="narbar-brand">User</h1>
  <button class="navbar-toggler">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: did you include bootstrap in your html file?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your html.

However, did you add js file (from bootstrap) to your html?

Answer (score 0):

check this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">User</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```